# How to deal with error "Coefficients: 2 not defined because of singularities" in R for factor variables?

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients

I ran multiple linear regression in R.
The coefficients for 2 levels of factor variables give me NA values and the message:
Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)

Please find the summary of the linear model below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/95y2i.png

Please find my code below:

```
ols <- lm(Inc_sales ~.-Page_nr, data = train)
summary(ols)
```

What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check your design matrix for collinearity.

Comment: It's easy to search our site for [error messages like this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22not+defined+because+of+singularities%22+) and the results tend to be exactly what you need.